# Code error. Getting wrong answer when it's perfect?

Tags: java

```
package Basics;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ForLoop {
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner Jee = new Scanner(System.in);
        int Final = 0;
        int HowManyRounds = 1;

        for (int counter = 1; counter <= HowManyRounds; counter++){

        System.out.println("Type your boundary: ");
        int Limit = Jee.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Type the number which you want the sum of all multiples in given boundary: ");
        int number = Jee.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Type your starting number: ");
        int StartingNumber = Jee.nextInt();
        for(int Answer =  StartingNumber; Answer <= Limit;Answer += number){        
        Final += Answer;
        }
      }
        System.out.println(Final);
        Jee.close();
    }
 }
```

i'm getting wrong answer. i don't know why. when i type 1000 for boundary 5 for round and 0 for starting number, i'm supposed to get 99500 but i'm getting 100500 and when i type for 1000 3 0, i'm getting right answer where as i get same answer for 99 3 0...

Type your boundary: 
1000
Type the number which you want the sum of all multiples in given boundary: 
5
Type your starting number: 
0
100500

Type your boundary: 
1000
Type the number which you want the sum of all multiples in given boundary: 
3
Type your starting number: 
0
166833

Type your boundary: 
999
Type the number which you want the sum of all multiples in given boundary: 
3
Type your starting number: 
0
166833

Comment: Please refrain from posting [Exact same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583141/im-getting-100500-when-i-put-5-but-i-get-right-answer-when-i-type-in-3-for-numb) twice. Instead update your previous question.

Comment: oh sorry. I'm new to this place :D Didn't know about that

Answer (score 1):

If you expect an answer of 99500 in the first case, that probably means you don't want to include the limit itself in your operation (which you are doing right now). Try to change the condition in the for loop to answer < limit (instead of <=):

```
for(int Answer =  StartingNumber; Answer < Limit;Answer += number){   
    [...]
```

Comment: that's now the problem yet. i'm getting a error at the bottom that final cannot be resolved a variable

Comment: That's not what your question says. It says you are getting the wrong answer: 99500 instead of 100500. That is what I am responding to.

Answer (score 0):

You are not zeroing `Final` when you start a new loop.

Instead, move the declaration of `Final` *inside* the loop:

```
for (int counter = 1; counter <= HowManyRounds; counter++){
    int Final = 0; // now Final is zeroed automatically for every iteration
    // rest of loop the same
}
```

And please adhere to java naming conventions: variables shoiuld start with a lowercase letter, ie `int total`, not `int Total`

---

You seem to having trouble making this work. Here's the whole method fixed, including fixing style issues. Whether the logic is correct, I can't say, because you haven't told us what it is you're actually doing.

```
private static final int ROUNDS = 3;

public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < ROUNDS; i++) {
        System.out.println("Type your boundary: ");
        int limit = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Type the number which you want the sum of all multiples in given boundary: ");
        int number = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Type your starting number: ");
        int start = keyboard.nextInt();
        int total = 0;
        for (int n = start; n <= limit; n += number) {        
            total += n;
        }
        System.out.println(total);
    }
    keyboard.close();
}
```

Comment: System.out.println(Final);
        Jee.close();

Comment: Also worth noting that `final` is a keyword, so it is not a good variable name (whether the first letter is capitalised or not)

Comment: @wakjah yes, quite so. I noticed that too when I went to type the example at the bottom... hence `total` :)

Comment: beside it's for multiple printing for finding the sum of sum of multiples of different numbers in a set boundary.

Comment: @Bohemian please can you note what you did?

Comment: all i need to know is why final at the last print is not connected to rest of it.

Comment: The scope of the `Final` variable is inside the for loop, which is by the way the only place you need it. Any attempt to use it outside the loop is an error. Note that I have assumed you don't want to total the numbers from *every* round (which seems unlikely).

Comment: the coding isn't finished yet. i have to add option to have how many rounds you want to have by typing the number and i need to write a code for 'total - sum of xy mutilples'.

Comment: final is the end answer which needs to be PRINTED which is the result you want

Comment: I give up... get something simple working and use a debugger to figure out what's going on when you add a bit more complexity and it stops working

Comment: it only prints the result for each round not the sum of all the results of the roundS

Comment: If that's what you wanted, then your original code should have worked OK.